# Image shift / offset

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I'm writing text with some custom images (symbols) in the text line, I add them using `\includegraphics`, but the images align with the text at the bottom, which is annoying, since the images are slightly larger than the text. How do I move the image a bit lower, so that the image stops just a bit below the text.

E.G. The diagram `$\includegraphics{images/diagram_A}$` is neat.

It would be nice to have in the $ enviroment.

Comment: Is having it between `$` symbols important? This seems like a very strange requirement.

Answer (score 12):

You may wrap your `\includegraphics{...}` into a `\raisebox`

**Edit:**

```
This is\raisebox{1ex}{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{/Users/brf/Pictures/logos/dode.PDF}}okay
```

Or create a newcommand:

```
\newcommand{\moveup}{[1]{%
\raisebox{1ex}{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{/Users/brf/Pictures/logos/#1}}}
```

Then blabla\moveup{dode.PDF}bla

Comment: Would you like to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Something like this: `raisebox{10pt}{stuff}` will move the stuff  10pt above the baseline.

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld Please include an example in your answer so that others may find it easier.